# Pyodbs : Login timeout expired

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a connection to SQL server management studio using python Python:
I tried the following code:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database}'
```

I got the following error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I'm using SQL server version 19 for what it's worth, any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: For some reason It was created twice, I remove the duplicated question, thanks

Comment: You don't have user specified in your connection string anywhere...

Comment: well the thing is this is from some code that used to function, idk why it stopped to now